# Create DataFrame with null value for few column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` using `RDD`.

First I am creating a `RDD` using below code -

```
val account = sc.parallelize(Seq(
                                 (1, null, 2,"F"), 
                                 (2, 2, 4, "F"),
                                 (3, 3, 6, "N"),
                                 (4,null,8,"F")))
```

It is working fine -

> account: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Any, Int, String)] =
>   ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at :27

but when try to create `DataFrame` from the `RDD` using below code

```
account.toDF("ACCT_ID", "M_CD", "C_CD","IND")
```

I am getting below error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not
>   supported

I analyzed that whenever I put `null` value in `Seq` then only I got the error.

Is there any way to add null value?

Comment: use `(1, null: Integer, 2,"F")`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that Any is too general type and Spark just has no idea how to serialize it. You should explicitly provide some specific type, in your case `Integer`. Since null can't be assigned to primitive types in Scala you can use `java.lang.Integer` instead. So try this:

```
val account = sc.parallelize(Seq(
                                 (1, null.asInstanceOf[Integer], 2,"F"), 
                                 (2, new Integer(2), 4, "F"),
                                 (3, new Integer(3), 6, "N"),
                                 (4, null.asInstanceOf[Integer],8,"F")))
```

Here is an output:

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Integer, Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24
```

And the corresponding DataFrame:

```
scala> val df = rdd.toDF("ACCT_ID", "M_CD", "C_CD","IND")

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ACCT_ID: int, M_CD: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+-------+----+----+---+
|ACCT_ID|M_CD|C_CD|IND|
+-------+----+----+---+
|      1|null|   2|  F|
|      2|   2|   4|  F|
|      3|   3|   6|  N|
|      4|null|   8|  F|
+-------+----+----+---+
```

Also you can consider some cleaner way to declare the null integer value like:

```
object Constants {
  val NullInteger: java.lang.Integer = null
}
```

Comment: How should I go about it if I'm using `case class` for creating `DataFrame`, i.e., I'm creating `DataFrame` using `spark.sparkContext.parallellize(Seq(A(_, _), A(_, _))).toDF()` where I have `case class A(_, _)`? I've tried above technique but `null.asInstanceOf[T]` is giving me `NullPointerException` and `null: T` (as told in comment on question) is giving me `an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion`

Answer (score 32):

Alternative way without using RDDs:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, None,    2, "F"),
  (2, Some(2), 4, "F"),
  (3, Some(3), 6, "N"),
  (4, None,    8, "F")
)).toDF("ACCT_ID", "M_CD", "C_CD","IND")

df.show
+-------+----+----+---+
|ACCT_ID|M_CD|C_CD|IND|
+-------+----+----+---+
|      1|null|   2|  F|
|      2|   2|   4|  F|
|      3|   3|   6|  N|
|      4|null|   8|  F|
+-------+----+----+---+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- ACCT_ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- M_CD: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C_CD: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- IND: string (nullable = true)
```